# Using themoviedatabase.org's database to fill my own database, best practices

Tags: database, api

I'm building a site where I want to allow users to keep wishlists of movies they want to see and movies they already have seen. To do this I want to use data from the movie tmdb, but I'm not sure how to handle this.

What if a user comes on my site and enters the query 'Batman', what is the next step I should take?

1. Search my own database for 'Batman'
2. Search API for 'Batman'
3. Merge results from own database and external and print, but don't save anything to my db

If a user then clicks on a result that's not in my database I would do another request to the API for the more detailed information, also saving images and so on before showing it to the user.

Is this the way I should go about this or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should browse API for this movie. Data in TMDB Api is often changing, so I suggest you not to store it for a long time in your db.

Comment: Well, I'd browse for it and if a user requests it the second time I could check when the data was requested and, if older than a week or so, compare it to their last update. But wouldn't I be putting too much strain on tmdb this way?

Comment: If I understood you, you want to check your db for requested movie and if valid period is expired, update it from tmdb api. I suppose if you do so, it would be a really good solution.